# Where is a list of the deprecated language codes that Java still uses?

Tags: java, android, localization

Per [Android Locale documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html):

> Note that Java uses several deprecated two-letter codes. The Hebrew ("he") language code is rewritten as "iw", Indonesian ("id") as "in", and Yiddish ("yi") as "ji". This rewriting happens even if you construct your own Locale object, not just for instances returned by the various lookup methods.

I'm trying to setup my servers to support both the current codes (Hebrew = he) and the deprecated codes (Hebrew = iw).  Are the three languages in the example above the only ones that I need to duplicate or is there a full list?

Comment: [Here's](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_changes.php) a start. Deprecated codes are within brackets. It contains your three examples and a few others.

Answer (score 0):

Java itself can list the letter codes for the avalable languages in the locales.

Here is an example to list all the supported language codes and to remove 
some codes that we don't want from the list :

```
public class TestLocale
{

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] allLangs = Locale.getISOLanguages();
    String[] deprecatedLangs = {"ji", "in", "iw"};
    ArrayList<String> validLangs = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(allLangs));
    validLangs.removeAll(Arrays.asList(deprecatedLangs));
    for (String lng : validLangs) {
      System.out.println(lng);
    }
  }

}
```

Of course this list (returned by Locale.getISOLanguages()) depends on your java
implementation; so I would set up a small servlet to return the result of this 
function invocation just to be able to check if the language that interests you 
is still supported when you switch from one java plaform to another.

Note also in the documentation the following comment on this method :

> [NOTE: ISO 639 is not a stable standard-- some languages' codes have changed. The list
>   this function returns includes both the new and the old codes for the languages whose 
>   codes have changed.]

Hope this helps,

Comment: Rather than getting Java to list the deprecated languages, your source code has cheated by hardcoding a list of deprecated languages. So I would argue that this hasn't answered the question at all. How did you arrive at {"ji", "in", "iw"}?